# How to send a email when import?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

I am trying send an email to a user, when a list is import.

But is not working. I am Using Mailtrap.

This is my code here i think where is the problem:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Imports\CsvImport;
use App\Mail\SuccessMail;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;
use function GuzzleHttp\Promise\all;


class CsvFile extends Controller
{
    function index()
    {
        return view('csv_file');
    }

    public function csv_import()
    {
        Excel::import(new CsvImport, request()->file('file'));
        return redirect('/home');

    }

    public function sendEmail()
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        Mail::to($user->email)->send(new SuccessMail());
    }

}
```

Comment: Where are you calling `sendEmail()`? I see the function defined, but it's never being used...

Comment: @TimLewis, this is my import controller

Comment: I am quite aware of that, but you're still never using `sendEmail()`...

Comment: @TimLewis, do i need change for anything else?

Comment: @seique3 you have to call the sendEmail() method to send email. Use it under ```csv_import()``` method before ```return redirect(...```

Comment: @jogesh_pi, thank you man, its working !!!!

Comment: Thank you @TimLewis for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `sendEmail()` function from `csv_import()` function :

```
public function csv_import()
    {
        Excel::import(new CsvImport, request()->file('file'));
        $this->sendEmail(); // then sendEmail function will execute
        return redirect('/home');
    }
```